# How to handle empty records of character type in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am reading a JSON txt file as a dataframe in R which has a lot of empty records. Now when I check is.na(df), I do not get TRUE for the empty records. How do I handle this?

I tried checking the empty records by printing and it shows as empty quotes "", which I believe is counted as characters by dataframe. I tried to replace these with NA but not sure if this is the correct way to handle this. Eventually, I would need to take care of these missing values.

is.na(df)

df[df==""]<-NA

What is the best way to handle the empty records as missing values and remove them from my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use `na.strings = ""` in the `read.table/read.csv` while reading the file.  If that is not possible, then one option other than the method used by the OP would be `na_if` and then change the `type` of the column if needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)
df <-  df %>%
           mutate_all(na_if, y = "") %>%
           retype
```

Comment: Thanks. na.strings = " " was the simplest solution.